# Add external javascript files with blade engine code in Laravel 5.x?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have multiple Javascript files, and lots of them are prepared by the laravel template engine. For example ill use:

```
@if ($group_id !== 3)
    //do something here
@endif
```

Everthing is fine, when ill include this the javascript code directly into my filename.blade.php template.

But i would like to load all external with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.getScript("js/pages/filename.js");
</script>
```

And so its not processed by the blade engine. Ill found some solutions for L4, but i am not really happy with them. For example youll should name your javascript files like javascript.blade.php and include it in that way - but so my IDE thinks its an PHP file and formats it totally wrong. Other solution here is to write your (group in this example) before you include it, like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var group = {!! $group_id !!}
    $.getScript("js/pages/filename.js");
</script>
```

I am still not really happy with that solution, i would like that all files should be processed as it was included directly in my blade-file.

Is there a solution to handle that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want add different files on each blade template? or the javascript file is loaded by validation using IF in blade?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes, there are several blade template files. For each template ill got a javascript file i would like to add. There are lots of custom code for different groups (in datatables for example) so it would be nice to created a processed JS file for a specific group. So the "if" is directly in the JS File.

Comment: I'm not getting your idea clearly, but if you want to load each file depending of group, you can create a section for extra files and into this section manage each group, and load the specific file. If this not the idea tell me.

Comment: No thats not a good idea. For example. Youll got 1 large Datatable, but the columns are different for each group, so ill modify the columns directly in javascript with blade for each group. I dont want to create multiple JS files with beneath the same content (just for each group) - i prefer 1 file that is processed by the blade engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say you have the following external JS script (including some blade engine code as well) :

> **first.js**

First of all in order to use this script in any of the other blade file, rename the above file to the following:

> **first.blade.php** (**But remember to place the whole script code inside script tag!!**)

Now include this file inside your other blade file in the following way:

**@include('someViewFolder.first')** assuming you had put the **first.blade.php** inside '**someViewFolder**' folder.

I hope this helps, Cheers.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your answer, the problem here is (as decribed above) that my IDE (PHPStorm) do not format correct javascript, if its a .php file. So it works fine, but is useless/hard to debug.